# Wordpress If statement using Post Thumbnail error

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm attempting to pull the post thumbnail within an if statement and if there is no post thumbnail than displaying a default image. I can't get the links to work properly. Here is what I have:

```
<?php $image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
    echo '<a href="<? php the_permalink() ?>"><img src=" <?php echo $image_link; ?>" width="125" height="84" /></a>';
    }
else {
    echo '<a href="<? php the_permalink() ?>" title=" <?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="http://www.myurl.com/defaultimg.jpg" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="125" height="84" /></a>';
    }
?>
```

It was properly pulling the `$image_link` before I used an `if` statement but I can't seem to find a way to pull it with the `if` statement.

I need the thumbnail to be `width="125" height="84"` and link to the post. Is there a smoother way to implement this default thumbnail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read more up on the difference between the WordPress functions `the_title` and `get_the_title` and where to use them, among echoing variables in php.

```
<?php $image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); 

if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
    echo '<a href="' . the_permalink() . '"><img src="' . $image_link . '" width="125" height="84" /></a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="' . the_permalink() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '"><img src="http://www.myurl.com/defaultimg.jpg" title="' . get_the_title() . '" width="125" height="84" /></a>';
}
?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

Comment: Thank you! Just so you know `the_permalink()` did not link to the content correctly it just displayed the permalink. `get_permalink` is what worked for me.

Comment: Ahh, `the_permalink` would work if it this was in the loop. Glad it's working though!

Answer (score 0):

This should clean it up a bit too.

```
<?php $image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
        echo '<a href="' . the_permalink() . '"><img src="' . $image_link . '" width="125" height="84" /></a>';
    }   else {
        echo '<a href="' . the_permalink() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '"><img src="http://www.myurl.com/defaultimg.jpg" title="' . get_the_title() . '" width="125" height="84" /></a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! Just so you know `the_permalink()` did not link to the content correctly it just displayed the permalink. `get_permalink` is what worked for me.